# jQuery won't hide form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three click events. Each one hides and shows different things depending on what is being clicked. Everything works except for the `<form>` with class `markas` doesn't get hidden when the `<p>` with class `cancel` is clicked.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".cancel").on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide().parent().find('.celltext, .editlink, .marklink').show().parent().find('.editas, .markas').hide();
});
$(".editlink").on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide().parent().find('.celltext, .marklink, .markas').hide().parent().find('.editas, .cancel').show();
    $(this).parent().find(".editas input:text").focus();
});
$('.marklink').on("click", function(){
    $(this).hide().parent().find('.celltext, .editlink, .editas').hide().parent().find('.markas, .cancel').show();
    $(this).parent().find(".editas input:text").focus();
});
```

The HTML is exactly what you would assume. I have used a similar code with strings of `.prev()` and `.next()` and everything was hidden and shown correctly. Since I know it's not the internal HTML structure, rather than paste unnecessary code (I am using php functions and code to gather info from a database), the general structure is this:

```
<div>
    <p class="celltext">Info from database</p>
    <p class-"editlink">Edit</p>
    <p class="marklink">Mark</p>
    <form class="markas">Form with select box to mark the cell</form>
    <form class="editas">Form with text fields to edit the info</form>
    <p class="cancel">Cancel</p>
</div>
```

I have tried to hide the form in a separate line on its own, but that doesn't work either. Why doesn't it hide and how do I get it to hide properly when cancel is clicked?

**UPDATE:**
It has to do with the order that the forms display in. I swapped markas and editas and now markas hides and editas doesn't.

Comment: Could you put your code into a jsFiddle?

Comment: Put contents of form in a DIV and give it the class. instead of the hiding the form, hide the div inside the form. Form is not a displaying element so there is nothing to show or hide.

Comment: @NawedKhan: If that were the issue, the code for the `editlink` and `marklink` click functions wouldn't successfully hide the `markas` form.  OP states that those work.

Comment: Without seeing a working example with the problem, I can't say for sure, but I suspect you are picking up more elements than you intend with the chained `find()` and `parent()` calls.  I'd suggest doing a `parentEl = $(this).parent(); $(this).hide();` at the start of all of your functions, then doing `parentEl.find(...).show();` and `parentEl.find(...).hide();`  It'll make your code easier to read, too.

Comment: You need to post your **actual** markup as your current mark-up in your post is invalid, causing your cancel `p` tag to be inside the `form`. This: `<form class="editas" /><p class="cancel" />` is invalid causing your markup to be actually rendered like this: `<form class="markas"><p class="cancel"></p></form>`, hence when `cancel` is clicked the selector will never find the correct elements. Please post a fiddle or similar so we can see what is causing the issue. You can use [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsBY2/) to see the problem (use debugger!) and add your actual code for testing.

Comment: All of the markup is valid. It's just a shorthand so you can get the idea. All the forms and paragraphs close like they should. @ConspicuousCompiler if you type up your comment as an answer, I will accept it. That solved the problem.

Comment: @user3735726: The problem with shorthand examples is that they are not your actual code and if the problem is a incorrect nested element causing the selector to be incorrect we wouldn't know. Hence the actual markup should always be included in a question. Also the problem can not be reproduced without the actual markup, making this question less useful to future users. Glad you got your issue sorted out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, this is the answer that solved the problem:

> Without seeing a working example with the problem, I can't say for
>   sure, but I suspect you are picking up more elements than you intend
>   with the chained find() and parent() calls. I'd suggest doing a
>   parentEl = $(this).parent(); $(this).hide(); at the start of all of
>   your functions, then doing parentEl.find(...).show(); and
>   parentEl.find(...).hide(); It'll make your code easier to read, too.

`$(".cancel").on("click", function(){
        var parentel = $(this).parent();
        $(this).hide();
        parentel.find('.celltext, .editlink, .marklink').show();
        parentel.find('.editas, .markas').hide();
    });`

Comment: This actually isn't working completely. I've wrapped the markas form in a div which isn't working either.

Comment: Nevermind. It does work. I had left the old `.cancel` onclick by mistake.